# Why does my callback function receive undefined as a parameter value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, callback

I am trying to use the very cool looking [Bootstrap Notify](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) plugin, and although it needs quite a lot of DIY styling, works very nicely.

Except, the plugin's main method, `$.notify(message, options & settings)` offers a settings property for an `OnClose` callback, when the notification popout (toast) is closed, either naturally or by clicking its `Dismiss` icon.

The code in the plugin invokes the callback like so:

```
if ($.isFunction(self.settings.onClose)) {
    self.settings.onClose.call(this.$ele);
}
```

in its `close` function, which is called when the user dismisses the alert, or when its delay time elapses and it auto-closes. When I examine the `this.$ele` value before being passed into the callback call, I see it is a jQuery like object representing an array of one element, i.e. the alert element busy removing itself from my window. E.i. an array containing this element:

```
<div data-notify="container" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-4 alert alert-minimalist animated fadeInDown fadeOutUp" role="alert" data-notify-position="top-right" data-closing="true" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; position: fixed; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; z-index: 1031; top: 20px; right: 20px;">
    <button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-notify="dismiss" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 5px; z-index: 1033;">×</button>
    <span data-notify="icon"></span>
    <span data-notify="title">
    </span> <span data-notify="message">Hey hey hey!</span><a href="#" target="_blank" data-notify="url"></a>
</div>
```

I use the notify plugin in a very simple test page, like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $.notify("Hey hey hey!", {
        type: "minimalist",
        delay: 50000,
        onClose: function(element) {
            console.log("Element: " + element);
        }
    });
});
```

Yet, when this `onClose` callback is invoked, its `element` parameter value is `undefined`. Why does this value become undefined between invoking the callback, and when the callback code is executed?

Comment: Try to do a console.log($(this)) within onClose to see if it prints out what you need.

Comment: perhaps the scope of `this` was lost. I just read a great article on how that happens with callbacks when you assign a method as a arg. http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the plugin:

```
self.settings.onClose.call(this.$ele);
```

does not pass any arguments to the `onClose()` callback.  The first argument to `.call()` is the `this` pointer that should be set for the callback.  Any subsequent arguments for `.call()` would be the actual arguments to the callback.  Since there are none, any that you look for will be `undefined`.

See [MDN doc for `.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more info.

So, if you want to access the element that is associated with this call, then you can use `this` inside the callback.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $.notify("Hey hey hey!", {
        type: "minimalist",
        delay: 50000,
        onClose: function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so what you're trying to say is that OP should use $(this) within onClose to get the element that was closed

Comment: @HieuLe - yes, you are correct - I added that to my answer - thx.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for an educational answer. I didn't really know anything about `call` until now. I have modified the plugin code to pass two of the same param values to `call`: `self.settings.onDismiss.call(this.$ele, this.$ele);` and my callback gets exactly the element I am expecting.

Comment: @ProfK - you didn't need to modify the plug-in.  You could have just used the `this` value instead of the callback argument.